# Python streamlit - subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, streamlit, npx

I have created a streamlit app which runs fine on my local machine. However, I cannot get it running on the streamlit-cloud. In a nutshell my app does the following:

1. take some user input
2. create a markdown file from the input ("deck.md")
3. convert markdown file to html file ("deck.html") using a `npx` command via `subprocess`
4. opens a new tab showing the html file via `subprocess`

On my local machine I use the following command to do steps 3 and 4:

```py
import subprocess
def markdown2marp(file):

    # Create HTML
    marp_it = f"npx @marp-team/marp-cli@latest --theme custom.css --html {file}"
    file = file.split(".")[0] # remove .md
    proc = subprocess.run([marp_it], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    # Open HTML in Browser  
    subprocess.Popen(['open', f'{file}.html'])
    return proc
```

Now on the streamlit cloud this is not working obviously.

**Question**: is there a workaround to achieve the described functionality in the streamlit-cloud.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/anthonywritescode/markdown-to-presentation)?